# Spring cloud sleuth + Spring Boot 1.4.0 transitive dependencies issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.0 and spring-cloud-sleuth, here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>spring-boot-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.igor.Application</start-class>
        <spring-cloud-sleuth.version>1.0.4.RELEASE</spring-cloud-sleuth.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-sleuth.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and here is my dependency tree:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building spring-boot-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ spring-boot-test ---
[INFO] spring-boot-test:spring-boot-test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.json:json:jar:20140107:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.126 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-07T20:25:23+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

it looks like spring-boot-sleuth has overridden dependencies, cause Spring Boot 1.4 uses spring 4.3.2.RELEASE.
I don't need it, how to avoid this behavior??

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: ok, but this is really error prone, I've spent a whole day to figure out why I have spring-core 4.2.6 instead of 4.3.2

Comment: "this is really error prone" - what's this? Maven dependency management, or your code?

Comment: my code - 
```

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-sleuth.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: That's not how to exclude transitive dependencies. Read the link I provided or Google.

Comment: I mean it's difficult to maintain this code if I need to upgrade Spring Boot version I have to upgrade sleuth as well

Comment: ok, thx for idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude dependencies in Maven. However you should consider using a release train BOM so that best matching dependencies are picked for you